# Angularjs date input allowing null input

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, string

Relatively new to Angularjs

I have read the date input documentation here:
[Angularjs Date Input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)
It states the model (the data the input is bound to) must be a JavaScript date object.

However, in my application, I want to be able display a date input field that is initially empty (except perhaps for a placeholder prompt).  If the user chooses not to enter a date, that is an acceptable circumstance.

My understanding is that a JavaScript date object always describes *some* date.  So the date input, since it is bound to the model, will *always* display some date.  And if the user overlooks or skips the date input, a date will still seem to have been provided.  I don't want that to happen.

The only solution I have think of would be to use a text edit field that can be empty or contain a date.  And then I would have to somehow parse out the user input.  But it wouldn't have a nice date picker.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this:  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: those same docs have an example that you can edit in plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/T2BkEmsBAPeTIMnYTtak?p=preview It appears that the input is initially empty as you want. Is that correct?

Comment: @craigb -- the plnkr code has 'new Date(0)' to make an empty date.  That is different from the link directly from the Angularjs page.  So I think you did that to make a null date.  And it is just what I wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: @lucuma That is a nice date picker!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can actually simply set the value to undefined.

`$scope.value = undefined` won't throw an error.

See working plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/5Nf9UeC5XApAAST1eRJX?p=preview (Edited from previous reply by OP.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I ended up making a solution that used a custom object to store the various date parts (months, days, years, etc), rather than binding to a JS Date.  I needed to be able to represent 2014, Aug 2014, and Aug 3 2014 all as valid inputs.  Thanks again!

Comment: Genius! Why didn't I think of that LOL

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Tete1805, it is the correct solution.

Just wanted to share a case i had experienced in this regard. A case in which it was returning me a value like "`0NaN-NaN-NaN`" that's while using : 
`document.getElementById('date'+index).value;`

It can be resolved by simply checking

```
if(document.getElementById('date'+index).value == "0NaN-NaN-NaN"){
//Error handling code here
}
```